# Supporting iOS 6 and armv6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am building my application for iOS6 and i want to support armv6 so i had added the armv6 in architecture and valid architecture. Now application is giving lot of errors when build on **apple llvm 4.1** but it compiles on **llvm gcc 4.2**. And when i build an Adhoc app using llvm gcc 4.2 then it's not installing on iphone 3GS and ipod 3G.

---

It's possible as **kenji** has given a [link in the accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5/12836808#12836808)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 removed support for building armv6 binaries.

You can't just add armv6 to the build settings, because the support to build it isn't there.

**Edited to add**

Since it was requested in the comments - confirmation for this comes from the [Xcode 4.5 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html)

[image]

Comment: It's not directly relevant, but for the sake of recording my experience somewhere: Apple will also reject applications built with an SDK prior to 6.0 that include an iPhone 5 launch image. So it appears they've very deliberately blocked any ability to support the new device while also supporting ARMv6 devices.

Comment: It's possible, take a look at this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5/12836808#12836808

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message in 4.4.1. Problem was solved by changing deployment target from 4.0 to 4.3 and removing armv6 from Architecture.