# iOS 6 - "application executable is missing required architecture: armv6"

Tags: ios, ios6

First, I have tried every answer for the question - [application executable is missing a required architecture armv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053466/application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture-armv6)

This worked last week before I downloaded iOS 6. Now I am getting the following error when validating my archive for distribution.

[image]

To my knowledge, the only change is iOS 6. So I believe there must be a *new* step I'm missing.

Comment: Did you download the new Xcode version? Maybe it changed the project settings and added another processor architecture?

Comment: It did update the project settings. I noticed *armv7s* was added. But *armv6* is still there.

Comment: Xcode 4.5 doesn't support compiling code for armv6.

See [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565157/supporting-ios6-and-armv6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XCode 4.5 no longer supports armv6 compilation. It may still exist in the architecture settings (from an older project) but it won't build them anymore. If you need to build for old  (as in armv6 based ) iPhones you can't support 6.0 in the same build (as you need Xcode 4.5 for that).

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 20):

Make sure the *iOS Deployment Target* is set to `iOS 4.3`.

Although your project settings might say `armv6`, it is not supported anymore in Xcode 4.5, nor are Deployment Targets below 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Cocos2d and Xcode 4.5:

When I created a new and not Cocos2d project in Xcode 4.5, it can be built for archiving without warning about missing any architecture.

However, when I create a new Cocos2d project, Xcode 4.5 gives a validate warning of missing armv6 and App Store refuses to accept the app.

After checking, I see that Cocos2d set automatically iOS Deployment Target to iOS 4.0. Change the value to iOS 4.3, and it will solve the problem.