# Validation fails with reference to armv6 but armv6 is not in the project

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, armv6

I am trying to update an application for the Apple App Store and when I attempt to validate it it fails with error "iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6".  The problem is that I don't reference armv6 that I can find and my ios deployment target is 4.3.  I am using xcode 4.5.1.

Settings:Architectures -> "armv7, armv7s" for all configurations.

I have already tried the information recommended here as well as other things with no success.
[iOS 6 - "application executable is missing required architecture: armv6"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608395/ios-6-application-executable-is-missing-required-architecture-armv6)

Comment: Have you gone into your projects build settings and searched for `armv6`? It is possible you have a link in there somewhere. Or maybe you are using a library that only supports armv6

Comment: I have searched extensively in my project settings, performed a find in workspace for "armv6" and checked the various frameworks I reference are coming from the ios6 libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The ios deployment target must be set for both the project and the target application.

Answer (score 0):

Add armv6 to the architecture  if your deployment target less 4.3